# Refresh datagridview in windows form application

Tags: datagridview, refresh

I have a form with datagridview and a List like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
            list.Add(new Person("A", "An Giang"));
            list.Add(new Person("B", "TP HCM"));
            list.Add(new Person("C", "Tiền Giang"));
            list.Add(new Person("D", "Cần Thơ"));

            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = list;

            list.Add(new Person("E", "Bạc Liêu")); // --> changed

            this.dataGridView1.EndEdit();
            this.dataGridView1.Refresh();
            this.Refresh();
            this.dataGridView1.Parent.Refresh();
        }
```

My problem is the datagridview didn't show the new row although its Datasource had changed. I try to refresh the datagrid but it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx), this is a list that supports databinding and as such it fires off events when the collection is modified.

Comment: All of you are fast than me. Thanks you very much. ^^

Answer (score 1):

A quick hack shows that this will rebind as you expect with your `List<t>`:

```
...
list.Add(new Person("E", "Bạc Liêu")); // --> changed

dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
```

Consider refactoring to use a `BindingList<Person>` instead of the `List<Person>`, which will perform as you expect, and you'll require none of the code to refresh. Implement this change, and all the code after inserting Person E can be deleted.

Comment: I had tried 
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.DataSource = list; 
but it flash the datagridview.

Answer (score 1):

Use this it worked for me:

qTableAdapter.Fill(_11DataSet.q);

Answer (score 0):

Answer my question. I've tried to use a `BindingList<Person>` instead of `List<Person>` and the problem solved.